# My Alarm Manager Doesn't show notification when app is closed?

Tags: android, notifications, alarm

I'm trying to trigger a notification when even app is closed but my Alarm manager doesn't shows notification when app is closed

Here is my code

```
start.setOnClickListener {
            createNotificationChannel()
            val intent = Intent(activity, MyReceiver::class.java)
            val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0)
            val alarmManager = getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE) as AlarmManager
            val time = System.currentTimeMillis()
            val tenssec = 100*10
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
                alarmManager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, time + tenssec,AlarmManager.INTERVAL_HALF_HOUR,  pendingIntent)
            else
                alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, time + tenssec, pendingIntent)
        }
```

this is how I'm creating notification Channel

```
private fun createNotificationChannel(){
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.O) return
        val channel = NotificationChannel("notifyme", "Medicine Time", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT)
        val manager = getSystemService(NotificationManager::class.java) as NotificationManager
        manager.createNotificationChannel(channel)

    }
```

And this is my Broadcast Receiver onReceive Method

```
override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent?) {
        val uri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION)
        val notificationCompat = NotificationCompat.Builder(context, "notifyme")
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_alert)
            .setContentTitle("It's time to Remind You")
            .setContentText("Let's take your medicine")
            .setSound(uri)
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT)
        val nI = Intent(context, MainActivity::class.java)
        val pI = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, nI, 0)
        notificationCompat.setContentIntent(pI)

        val manager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(context)
        manager.notify(200, notificationCompat.build())
    }
```

Comment: instead of `setInexactRepeating` try `setExactAndAllowWhileIdle`  .

Comment: @ManoharReddy this worked when app was closed... but didn't worked when app is killed

Comment: Few companies kill all the alarms when app is killed so not much can be done in that case .